# Satellite data to watch atmosphere and ionosphere

Tags: data, satellite

Which bandwidths are best suited to watch atmosphere and ionosphere of  a region?

What are the sources (satellite sensors/names etc)?

I want to monitor temporal changes of atmospheric and ionospheric constituents.

Answer (score 1):

The Multi-spectral Observatory Of Sensitive EMCCDs (MOOSE) might have some useful info.
http://moose.space.swri.edu/data_availability